# U boat WW1 activity west of Ireland

Tags: world-war-1, navy, merchant-navy

Currently researching **U-boat World War 1** activity on the west coast of Ireland.  Attached is a copy of Defence of Realm Act Nov 1914.

Source: http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/pathways/firstworldwar/first_world_war/p_defence.htm

Also attached is a copy of a Petty Court Session in Mayo 1918, Steelaun where a relative of mine was fined for having a light in her house visible during sunset and sun rise in contravention of realm act.  There was U Boat activity all around this coast line area. There is also anecdotal info on U Boats stopping at lighthouses, isolated inlets along coast etc. for fresh supplies as bread, milk from sympathetic parties?

Please note electrifcation did not occur until the late 1940S

https://esbarchives.ie/2017/09/18/electrifying-ireland-how-esb-connected-one-million-irish-homes-to-the-national-grid-1929-1978/ [image]

I am seeking an example of a sighting of a U boat in the Achill / Belmullet / Killala region of Mayo 1914 - 1918 .[image: Petty court mayo 1918]

[image: Def of Realm 1914]

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you're asking, please. Requests for 'any info' or any input' don't fit on this site -- what EXACTLY do you want to know.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Presumably he is trying to verify a family story and/or the information in the petty court session, but it would have been useful to have that stated explicitly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

http://westmayo.ie/german-submarines-in-north-mayo/

Memoirs of Henry, Michael. "BMH.WS1732", Page 3.

http://www.militaryarchives.ie/collections/online-collections/bureau-of-military-history-1913-1921/reels/bmh/BMH.WS1732.pdf

> A German submarine made contact with some fishermen off the coast. A
> fuelling was established. Our organisation had nothing whatever to do
> with this. It appears one Gallagher, a sailor from Belmullet, found
> his way into the German service, and it was through him contact was
> made with two brothers (Walsh) pals of Gallagher. Petrol was conveyed
> some twenty-five miles to the townland of Carrateigue, German arms of
> some description were landed. This was virgin country, as we [the IRA]
> had not as yet penetrated, but as a result of information received I
> interviewed one Rowen, of Stonefields, Carrateigue. I arranged a
> further A German submarine made contact with Furthermore I was
> presented with a German Parrabellum by the He didn't deny or confirm
> anything. I arranged a further meeting, but he newer turned up. I'm
> confident that some arms and ammunition were landed, as years later,
> while working as foreman in the same district, on road construction
> and demolishing an old house for road, I found some rifle bullets in
> walls; the bullets were of foreign origin. Furthermore I was presented
> with a German Parrabellum by the local teacher - Master Doherty
> (deceased). This weapon was later, while in the custody of another
> man, captured by the then Free State army.

Stonefields, Carrateigue : 54.311663238479646, -9.827969391167409

https://goo.gl/maps/8rutod98DyW7MSdKA